# How does this code returns array object of the clicked button

Tags: javascript

Entire Code : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NihilisticSin/9mp7jgtv/)

The code returns the array Object of the specific note of the 'x' button when it is clicked

How does this code do it ?

```js
const generateNoteDOM = function(note) {
  const noteEl = document.createElement('div')
  const textEl = document.createElement('span')
  const button = document.createElement('button')

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(note)
    // This thingy right here returns the array object
  })

  // Setup the remove note button
  button.textContent = 'x'
  noteEl.appendChild(button)

  // Setup the note title text
  if (note.title.length > 0) {
    textEl.textContent = note.title
  } else {
    textEl.textContent = 'Unnamed note'
  }
  noteEl.appendChild(textEl)

  return noteEl
}
```

Expected Output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVOtW.png

what i got when i tried to recreate the code was the entire array, not the specific array Object respective to the note of which 'x' button was clicked

Comment: Could you please share the code where you call `generateNoteDOM()`

Comment: `generateNoteDOM = function (note) {` passes `note` to the event listener. Instead of `console.log(note)` try `this` or `button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {` and use `e`.

Comment: JS fiddle link at the top or https://jsfiddle.net/NihilisticSin/9mp7jgtv/

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior in? I'm in Chrome, and your fiddle appears to produce the expect output

Comment: uhh, The one in Fiddle is the correct code by someone else, Q was for the explanation regarding the console output

Comment: Then please share where you call `generateNoteDOM()` in your version

Comment: `console.log` and `return` are completely different. The code here **returns** a single element. The console.log **prints** whatever param is passed in, which is **expected** to be an object with key 'title', but it may very well be an array of random numbers.

Comment: generateNoteDOM() is called in this function : `const renderNotes = function (notes, filters) {
    const filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
    })

    document.querySelector('#notes').innerHTML = ''

    filteredNotes.forEach(function (note) {
        const noteEl = generateNoteDOM(note)
        document.querySelector('#notes').appendChild(noteEl)
    })
}`  To view the complete Code :  jsfiddle.net/NihilisticSin/9mp7jgtv